# Why get() method doesn't return any value?

Tags: python, file, tkinter

```
def Main_Menu():
    for widget in myframe_1.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    PostIt_Count = len([name for name in os.listdir('C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts')])
    if PostIt_Count > 0:
        for i in range(PostIt_Count):
            PostIt_NamesList = [name for name in os.listdir('C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts')]
            global selected_postit
            selected_postit = tk.StringVar()
            PostIt_ButtonName = ttk.Radiobutton(myframe_1, text=PostIt_NamesList[i], variable=selected_postit)
            y = ([x for x in range(1, PostIt_Count +1)][i])- 0.4
            if PostIt_Count < 10:
                y = str(y)[:1] + str(y)[2:]
            else:
                y = str(y)[:2] + str(y)[3:]
            yname = '.' + y
            PostIt_ButtonName.place(relx=.1, rely=yname)

def Read_PostIt():
    for widget in myframe_3.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    filepath = 'C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts/'
    postit = selected_postit.get()
    print(postit)
    f = filepath + postit
    print(f)
    os.chmod('C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts/', stat.S_IRWXO)
    with open('{}'.format(f), 'r') as fi:
        global text
        text = fi.readlines()
        fi.close()
    text_label = Label(myframe_3, text='{}'.format(text))
    text_label.place(relx=.01, rely=.01)
```

I'm doing a Post-It app. There are post-its listed as radiobuttons with the name of their filenames. The idea is that when I select a radiobutton and click Read-button, the Read_PostIt function would read the post-it file and show the text. However, when the selected_postit.get()  line should return me the name of the post-it, it doesn't return anything. ```print(postit)´´´ just prints an empty line. Why is this?

Here is the output and traceback:

```
PS C:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit> & C:/Python39ni/python.exe c:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/post-its.py

C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts/
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39ni\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit\tkinterstuff\PostItApp\post-its.py", line 77, in Read_PostIt
    with open('{}'.format(f), 'r') as fi:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts/'
```

The program should add the name of the post-it at the end of its directory path but nothing appears at the end.

Someone pls help.

Comment: are you really combining pascal case with smake case? thats unreadable

Comment: also we need minimal reproducable example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `StringVar` each time through the loop, so each radio button is tied to a different one. After the loop, `selected_postit` is the `StringVar` associated with the last radio button, not all of them.

Create the `StringVar` once, and associate all the buttons with it.

Another problem is that you didn't set the `value` of the radio buttons, so it's defaulting to its integer sequence in the group.

```
    if PostIt_Count > 0:
        global selected_postit
        selected_postit = tk.StringVar()
        for i in range(PostIt_Count):
            PostIt_NamesList = [name for name in os.listdir('C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts')]
            PostIt_ButtonName = ttk.Radiobutton(myframe_1, text=PostIt_NamesList[i], value=PostIt_NamesList[i], variable=selected_postit)
            y = ([x for x in range(1, PostIt_Count +1)][i])- 0.4
            if PostIt_Count < 10:
                y = str(y)[:1] + str(y)[2:]
            else:
                y = str(y)[:2] + str(y)[3:]
            yname = '.' + y
            PostIt_ButtonName.place(relx=.1, rely=yname)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that. But I fixed that and now the get()  -method returns just "1". Why?!

Comment: You need to give the radio buttons a `value`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that either. Thank you mate!